# Is it necesary to use ManyToOne/OneToMany annotations on microservice arquitecture projects with Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, one-to-many, many-to-one

I'm creating this project were i have to create views using different entities from different schemes, as microservices do. It is my first microservice project. Is it necessary to use those relations annotations, even when i have to cross info manually with the rest controllers?

Comment: You can use JDBC if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best answer is **it depends**. And there is no right or wrong answer.

Basically a microservice encapsulates the business logic specific to a domain (order, email, user, etc).

Generally speaking it is a good idea to have a separate database for each microservice in order to have better decoupling.

If that database, for a clear reason, is a relational database (it can be any database) and the JPA is becoming helpful (defining relations, having transactions, etc.) then you should definitely use them. An alternative could be to use directly the JDBC.

In a microservice architecture you basically lose the transactionability and to achieve a something similar is by far more difficult.

Keep in mind that microservices add a lot more complexity to your projects, in all aspects.

With this context in mind, coming back to your question, you should use it if you need it.

Comment: But how could i use those kind of relations (JPA), if the data is separated in different databases?

Comment: You don't use them between microservices, you use them only inside each service if needed. The relation between microservices transforms into a communication mechanism of requests/responses or events with messages (depending on the type of communication you adopt). For example if you have a relationship of `@OneToMany` between `this` and `that` and `this` and `that` become microservices, then on `that` you will need to have a way to provide the data required by `this`. Since I mentioned this be careful about N+1 queries/requests https://restfulapi.net/rest-api-n-1-problem/

Comment: Then only if i have some intern relationship on a service should i use the annotations?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you can't use them. JPA annotations work as expected only within the application (service).